# Ignore namespace in XPath as this can be dynamic

Tags: xml, xpath, powershell-3.0

I've done extensive research over the last few hours on here, blogs and internet in general. However, nothing I've tried is working so far for me.
What I have is an xml file being generated with the following namespace:

```
<DeploymentReport xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02">
```

I have no control over the generation process of this file. As I understand, its a common problem for XPath not to work with namespaces unless they're registered or removed. I would prefer not to make any modifications to the xml document, and thought may be it would be better to somehow make it ignore it.

I've tried using `/name()=` and I've tried using `local-name` in my Xpath query (the basic version of which is):

```
//Operations/Operation/Item[@Type!='SqlIndex' and not(contains(@Value, 'Export'))]
```

However, none of these methods worked. Perhaps, its because I'm using Powershell version 3, if this matters?

The reason why I **don't want** to register the namespace, is because its tied up to the Sql version being locally installed (the file will be generated with that version). Which would mean it will cause problem with any other version. I don't want to register a whole lot of them and guess which ones they'll be to accommodate ones coming out in the future.

I would appreciate if someone could please suggest a good way of handling this situation? Or do I have no hope but to register the namespace and keep it up to date with each Sql release?

Comment: How did you use `local-name()`?

Comment: Yeah I think looking at answer, I now realise I had a typo: //*[local-name()='Operations']/*[local-name()='Operation']/*[local-name()='Item[@Type!='SqlIndex' and not(contains(@Value, 'Export'))]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `local-name()` should've worked (wrapped for readability):

```
//*[local-name()='Operations']
 /*[local-name()='Operation']
 /*[local-name()='Item'][@Type!='SqlIndex' and not(contains(@Value, 'Export'))]
```

Comment: Thank you! Now looking at your answer I realise I had a typo *face palm* :
 //*[local-name()='Operations']/*[local-name()='Operation']/*[local-name()='Item[@Type!='SqlIndex' and not(contains(@Value, 'Export'))]'

So annoying when you get caught on little things))

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that XPath doesn't work with namespaces. It's simply not very handy, that's all.

If you can manage to define a namespace prefix like

```
xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02"
```

then it's quite easy to address your Xml elements. Your XPath expression would then be:

```
//s:Operations/s:Operation/s:Item[@Type!='SqlIndex' and not(contains(@Value, 'Export'))]
```

If it's impossible to declare a namespace prefix in your context, then you're in trouble.

The full expression would then be (wrapped for readability):

```
//*[local-name()='Operations'][namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02']
 /*[local-name()='Operation'][namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02']
 /*[local-name()='Item'][namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02']
   [@Type!='SqlIndex' and not(contains(@Value, 'Export'))]
```

Of course it will still work if you omit the `[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02']`, but then you might accidentally also address elements with the same name in a different namespace, if there are any in your Xml document.

In higher XPath versions, you may also use

```
//*:Operations/*:Operation/*:Item[@Type!='SqlIndex' and not(contains(@Value, 'Export'))]
```

to ignore the namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, you've missed the fact from my post, that I have no control over how and what XML is being generated in the file, as this happens by 3rd party software

Comment: Depending on your context, it may not be necessary to declare the namespace prefix withing the source Xml.